# Software implementation of direct memory access when working with I/O devices

Tags: windows, io, filesystems, cpu-architecture, dma

I need to write a program that moves a file from hard drive to flash drive using direct memory access. How can i make it on Windows?

Comment: Windows drivers for your hard drive will already use DMA.  Probably also the flash drive via USB drivers.  So make normal open/read/write system calls.  Or write your own OS if you want to talk to the hardware yourself.

Comment: Another approach using windows would be to write your own device driver.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: DMA has a specific meaning, but perhaps you mean something else, like using memory mapped files?